# Remove subview of tableview cell with tag

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to remove a subview from tableview cells which i added like

```
subView.tag = 300;
[cell.contentView addSubView:subView];
```

with this method

```
[cell.contentView viewWithTag:300] performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperView)];
```

but its not working

Here is the complete code

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Check if custom subvie already present.If yes, remove and return
    if(![tableView isEditing])
    {
        [[cell.contentView viewWithTag:REORDER_CONTROL_TAG] performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        return;
    }

    //  Grip customization code goes in here...
    UIView* reorderControl = [cell huntedSubviewWithClassName:@"UITableViewCellReorderControl"];

    UIView* resizedGripView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetMaxX(reorderControl.frame), CGRectGetMaxY(reorderControl.frame))];
    resizedGripView.tag = REORDER_CONTROL_TAG;
    [resizedGripView addSubview:reorderControl];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:resizedGripView];

    CGSize sizeDifference = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width - reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height - reorderControl.frame.size.height);
    CGSize transformRatio = CGSizeMake(resizedGripView.frame.size.width / reorderControl.frame.size.width, resizedGripView.frame.size.height / reorderControl.frame.size.height);

    //  Original transform
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    //  Scale custom view so grip will fill entire cell
    transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, transformRatio.width, transformRatio.height);

    //  Move custom view so the grip's top left aligns with the cell's top left
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -sizeDifference.width / 2.0, -sizeDifference.height / 2.0);

    [resizedGripView setTransform:transform];

    for(UIImageView* cellGrip in reorderControl.subviews)
    {
        if([cellGrip isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
            [cellGrip setImage:nil];
    }
}
```

I am following this tutorial

http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/

but the problem is once the subviews are added , i cannot get touch events on the buttons within the cell.Thats why I'm trying to remove them

Iterating through the content views subviews reveals that there is no subview with the given tag.Why can't i find it ?

Comment: In what method are you trying to remove the subview? Are you iterating the subviews before or after removing the view?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on adding the subview and check if `cell.contentView` is `nil`. If it is, then your subview is not being added. Also check if `subView` is `nil` when you add it.

Comment: the subview is being added.I set a black background for it and its showing up on all cells

Comment: I'm adding and removing the subviews in the same method but under different if conditions.The for in  loop iterates over some subviews , but what i get is none of them have tag = 300

Comment: i want to delete the subview if the cells isEditing property is NO.

Comment: First, verify if your contentView contains viewwittag 300, then verify to sure that you call this REMOVE in mainthread. If you have to add then remove, then add, ... the subviews, you can add 1 time then play with alpha =0.0 or 1.0

Comment: You need to show more code. There's no context in what you posted so far.

Comment: Are you reusing cells (as you should be for a tableview)? If so, and you're searching through cells in a table, they may have been dequeued, and the one you're looking for may be in the dequeued list.  It's generally not a good idea to attach information to a reusable tableview cell as it's likely to show up in an entirely different position.

Comment: @rmAddy.. i have added more code

Comment: Cell's get reused. The code you posted keeps adding more and more subviews to the cell. Only add a subview if it isn't there already.

Comment: @rmaddy ... yes that is certainly an issue .But my primary concern here is getting back the responsiveness of my buttons when the reordering is done

Comment: if the UIView is custom view, did you try overriding the following methods,- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;.???

Comment: no... let me try that way